# Do something on select option switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some issue in my select option script, but I can not figure out, whats wrong? Sorry, I am not really a pro at jquery.

HTML

```
<fieldset>
<select id="sorting">
    <option value="1">A-Z</option>
    <option value="2">Number</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).change(function() {
    if( $("#sorting").prop("selectedIndex", 1) ) {
      alert("A-Z");
    }
    else if( $("#sorting").prop("selectedIndex", 2) ) {
      alert("Number");
    }         
});
```

My problem: Its always "A-Z" and I can not switch to "Number" by selecting number ;(.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bymfjrfk/)

Comment: Pretty straight forward -> https://jsfiddle.net/bymfjrfk/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.val()` to get the select's value:

```js
$("#sorting").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    alert("A-Z");
  } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
    alert("Number");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <select id="sorting">
    <option value="1">A-Z</option>
    <option value="2">Number</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting not getting the selected index but index is also zero based

Change to:

```
$(document).on('change','#sorting', function() {
    var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    if( selectedIndex  === 0 ) {
      alert("A-Z");
    }
    else if( selectedIndex  === 1 ) {
      alert("Number");
    }         
});
```

Comment: Ouh, damn, that makes sense! Thx!

Comment: I select j08691 solution, because its a bit smarter, but I vote your version up, because you help me to finde the fail in my script version - so thanks too!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the **value** in HTML property, so use the **.val()** in jQuery to get the value of the option.